# Discrete space, such as Integers $\mathbb {Z}$, does not have any limit point, is my understanding right?

Tags: general-topology

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) says:

> If $X$ is a discrete topological space, then every point is isolated and cannot be a limit point of any set.

So the set of integers $\mathbb {Z}$ does not have any limit point, is my understanding right?

Comment: Do you mean in the normal topology?

Comment: by normal topology do you mean a normal space in the context of topology?

Comment: By "normal topology", fleablood probably means the euclidean topology, which is often referred to as the standard, usual or normal topology - which are awful, uniformative, misleading, ambiguous terms that should never be used, if you ask me. Call it euclidean and there is no risk of confusion.

Comment: @MarsPlastic . I am ok with "usual" or "standard" but not "normal", which has (too many) special meanings in math. Normal space, normal subgroup, normal (ultra)filter, orthonormal, unit normal,...

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I absolutely agree that "normal" is by far the worst, for the reasons you list. "Usual" and "standard" are still unnecessarily vague, and the fact that the term "euclidean" is universally understood and entirely unambiguous makes it downright silly to use any other word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you think of $\Bbb Z$ as a topological subspace of the euclidean space $\Bbb R$. Then, the corresponding subspace topology is the discrete topology (i.e. it contains all singletons), so your understanding is right. However, if you equip $\Bbb Z$ with other topologies (e.g. the topology $\{\emptyset,\Bbb Z\}$), this need not be true.